# Set style of an element based on HTML attribute

Tags: html, jquery, css, flexbox

I have a div with several child divs like this:

```
<div class=container>
  <div data-value="3">div 1</div>
  <div data-value="2">div 2</div>
  <div data-value="1">div 3</div>
  <div data-value="2">div 4</div>
</div>
```

I need to set the `flex` attribute of each to its `data-value`. I came up with this:

```
$('.container > div').css('flex', $(this).attr('data-value'));
```

but that doesn't work - probably because that's not how `$(this)` is used.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need JS.

```css
.container { display: flex; }
.container > * {  outline: 1px solid gold; }

[data-value]     { flex: 1; }  /* default to 1 */
[data-value="2"] { flex: 2; }
[data-value="3"] { flex: 3; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div data-value="3">div 1</div>
  <div data-value="2">div 2</div>
  <div data-value="1">div 3</div>
  <div data-value="2">div 4</div>
</div>
```

Or without hardcoding values — by using [CSS var()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var()):

```css
.container { display: flex; }
.container > * { flex: var(--flex); outline: 1px solid gold;  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div style="--flex:3">div 1</div>
  <div style="--flex:2">div 2</div>
  <div style="--flex:1">div 3</div>
  <div style="--flex:2">div 4</div>
</div>
```

If you totally need JavaScript - than you don't need jQuery

```js
document.querySelectorAll("[data-value]").forEach(el => el.style.flex = el.dataset.value);
```

```css
.container { display: flex; }
[data-value] { outline: 1px solid gold;  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div data-value="3">div 1</div>
  <div data-value="2">div 2</div>
  <div data-value="1">div 3</div>
  <div data-value="2">div 4</div>
</div>
```

If you totally need jQuery (— which you don't, in 2022):

```js
$("[data-value]").css("flex", function () {
  return $(this).attr("data-value");
});
```

```css
.container { display: flex; }
[data-value] { outline: 1px solid gold;  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div data-value="3">div 1</div>
  <div data-value="2">div 2</div>
  <div data-value="1">div 3</div>
  <div data-value="2">div 4</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't even consider the CSS variable solution. Elegant!

Comment: @ProkopHanzl totally elegant :) Although I always suggest not to use the inline `style` attribute - this is one of the cool cases where its use pros might better argument the cons - by the means of passing HTML values into CSS.

Answer (score -1):

First put "" around the "container" attribute value in the parent div.

I think you'll need to use a .each() to loop over all the elements you want, then $(this) will refer to each element in turn.

So something like this...

```
$('.container > div').each(function() {
    $(this).css('flex', $(this).attr('data-value')); 
});
```

See https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Not the downvoter, but FYI, in HTML5 you only need quote wrappers around attributes where you need a space delimiter: `class=foo` *valid*, `class=foo bar` *not valid* — whilst `class="foo bar"` is finally valid. Also, most jQuery Methods internally already loop the $() Collection. `.css()` is one of them, accepting as first argument the CSS property to target, and exposes `this` as the currently iterating Element in collection. `return` can be then used to set that property new value. So, no need to `.each()` something that is already *forEach-able* :)

Comment: Thanks @RokoC.Buljan, I guess I'm old school :)